# Вывод двумерного массива

Tags: java

Нужно вывести двумерный массив, но на выходе получаю не тот формат символов

```
if ("next4".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        massNums();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainWindow.this,
                "Табличка\n" + Arrays.toString(tableNum),
                "Задание 4", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Генерация массива

```
public void massNums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
            tableNum[i][j] = (int) i * j;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для многомерных массивов нужен другой метод - [Arrays.deepToString(tableNum)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])).